# Flexbox with AngularJS 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, flexbox

I have components created with `ng-repeat` and I want them to be flex children:

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data" style="flex-basis: 30%">
        <my-component item="item"></my-component>
    </div>
<div>
```

Where my component's template is:

```
<div class="c">
    ...
</div>
```

It is kind of working, but the `my-component` items are not all in the same height as they would have been if they were simply `div`s.

I can workaround this by setting `.c{height: 100%}` but it messes up with the wrapping.

Can I acheive this behaviour with AngularJS 1.5 at all?

Attached codepen for repro: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENqvvO

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when using the component you have a new element wraping the `div.c` element, so that the flex behaviour doesn't bound the two elements of your css. Your example (from plunkr) without the component works because it doesn't have the `my-component` in between.

```
div.flex-container
    my-component // <- this guy is breaking off the flex connection
        div.c
```

In order to fix it you can style the tag `my-component` instead of `.c` so that the flex can be applied directly between `div.flex-container` and `my-component`.

Actually I recommend you to create a container component and an item component so that things are kept clear and solid.

For example:

```
<list>
    <list-item>Item 1</list-item>
    <list-item>Item 2</list-item>
    <list-item>Item 3</list-item>
    <list-item ng-repeat="item in items"> {{ item }} </list-item>
</list>
```

And also:

```
<gallery>
    <gallery-item ng-repeat="photo in photos">
        <photo img="photo "></photo>
    </gallery-item>
</galery>
```

> *Beautiful, isn't it? :{D*

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, adding a wrapper component works (like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNMdZE), but why can't this be achieved with current DOM elements?

Comment: @bomba6 because the component's tag isn't replaced by its template, it wraps his content inside his tag and because of that element isn't flex, it breaks off the relation with the wrapper and the item that is flex as well. Basicaly you have `flex - block - flex` and the block breaks off every thing.

Comment: Yes, the codepen I attached in the comment above is my implementation with a wrapper component. I'm not sure adding a component just for the sake of fixing this is the solution (I already have a `my-components` that renders some stuff and then renders `my-component` using ng-repeat). I'm trying to solve this *without* adding any more components.

Comment: @bomba6 what about styling the `my-component`? Or adding the class to your component like `my-component class="c"`? Just make your component flex.